# Xpath - sum multiplication

Tags: xpath

Im crawling a webpage using Xpath and I need to write the deposit as a number.
The deposit needs to be ("monthly rent" x "amount of prepaid rent")
the result should be: 15450 in this case

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>monthly rent: </td>
<td>5.150,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>deposit: </td>
<td>3 mdr.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am currently using the following XPath to find the info:

```
//td[contains(.,'Depositum') or contains(.,'Husleje ')]/following-sibling::td/text()
```

But I don't know how to remove "mdr." from deposit, and how to multiply the to numbers and only return 1 number to the database.

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: I'm currently using Xpath(not sure about the version) to select a part of the text, and regex seperate to select/remove certain parts.

Comment: Yes, but are you using Ruby, Python, PHP or ...?

Comment: Im sending it to a blackbox which handle it+stores it in a db, which means, if I can't do it purely with Xpath, it isn't possible.

Comment: Then this isn't possible, unless your black box supports XQuery.

Comment: It is not true that this is not possible using XPath. It is true for 1.0, but if your processor supports XPath 2.0 or even 3.0 it is possible. You should check which version is supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query which is compatible with XPath 1.0 and upwards:

```
substring-before(//td[contains(.,'deposit:')]/following-sibling::td/text(), ' mdr.') * translate(//td[contains(.,'monthly rent:')]/following-sibling::td/text(), ',.', '') div 100
```

Output:

```
15450
```

Step by Step Explanation:

```
// Get the deposit and remove mdr. from it using substring-before
substring-before(//td[contains(.,'deposit:')]/following-sibling::td/text(), ' mdr.')

// Arithmetic multiply operator
* 

// The number format 5.150,00 can't be used for arithmetic calculations.
// Therefore we get the monthly rent and remove . and , chars from it.
// Note that this is equal to multiply it by factor 100. That's why we divide
// by 100 later on.
translate(//td[contains(.,'monthly rent:')]/following-sibling::td/text(), ',.', '')

// Divide by 100
div 100
```

You can refer to the [List of Functions and Operators supported by XPath 1.0 and 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, it really helped, the only have "mdr" at the end once in a while, is possible to say "either end with 'mdr', '.' or ''"? again thank you and @jasso aswell

Comment: do you have xpath 2.0? If yes, you can use `replace()` instead of `substring-before()` otherwise it will can "more complicated" :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Can you please look into my problem and solve me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189178/match-an-element-with-a-dynamic-attribute-value

Answer (score 0):

Pure XPath solution:

```
translate(
    /table/tr/td[contains(., 'monthly rent')]/following-sibling::td[1],
    ',.',
    '.'
)
* 
substring-before(
    /table/tr/td[contains(., 'deposit')]/following-sibling::td[1],
    ' mdr'
)
```

It seems I ended up with a solution quite much similar to hek2mgl's correct answer but there is no need for dividing with 100 (comma converted to dot, dot removed) and `<td>` elements containing numeric data have positional predicates in order to avoid matching more elements, if the actual table is not as simple as the given example. XPath number format requires decimal separator to be a dot and no thousand separators.