# Match an element with a dynamic attribute value

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

I'm trying to prototype a transform to turn `xsl:schema` into a php interface. I'm having a little trouble matching `xsd:simpleType` elements that have a `name` attribute matching the `type` attribute of `xsd:element` elements. Suppose I have a schema like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Foo" type="Bar"/>
  <xsd:simpleType name="Bar">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="32"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I'd like to have the following result.

```
<?php
interface Foo {
  public abstract function buildFooXmlString(Bar $a);
}
```

Here's the xslt I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">&lt;?php <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:schema"/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="xsd:schema">interface FromXsd { <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:element"/> }</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="xsd:element">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:annotation"/>
    abstract public function build<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@name)"/>XmlString(<xsl:apply-templates select="@type"/>);
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="xsd:annotation">/* <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/> */</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@type"><xsl:apply-templates select="//xsd:simpleType[@name=normalize-space()]"/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="xsd:simpleType"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> $a</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces most of the desired result, but doesn't include anything inside the parentheses:

```
<?php
interface Foo {
  public abstract function buildFooXmlString();
}
```

How can I select the `simpleType` node with the `name` attribute matching the `type` of the `element`? (Names have to be unique for xsd types.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `simpleType` node is never selected because in the template where you match `xsd:schema`, you only apply the templates to the `xsd:element` child subtree. The `xsd:simpleType` sibling will never be processed.

If you want to allow the processing of all children of a node, you should include an empty `<xsl:apply-templates/>` inside the `xsd:schema` template.

That still won't generate the result you want. It's actually much simpler. To generate the code fragment you expect, you don't need to read the `xsd:simpleType` element, since the attribute that contains the type you want can be directly obtained from the `@type` attribute of `xsd:element` using `xsd:value-of`, and you can just print the `$a` immediately after it:

```
XmlString(<xsl:value-of select="@type"/> $a)
```

Since you are generating text, you should use the `<xsl:text>` elements to control how your whitespace will be distributed. For instance, if you use:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>&lt;?php </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:schema"/>
</xsl:template>
```

You won't need to worry about always placing the `&lt;?php` text immediately after the `<xsl:template>` and can indent your code normally. You can also include newlines with the `&#xa;` character (and it won't break your formatting):

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
    <xsl:text>interface FromXsd {&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:element"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:annotation"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

I edited your XSL and made these changes in the XSL document below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>&lt;?php </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:schema"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
        <xsl:text>interface FromXsd {&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:element"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:annotation"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:element">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:annotation"/>
        <xsl:text>    abstract public function build</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@name)"/>
        <xsl:text>XmlString(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/><xsl:text> $a</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>);</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:annotation">
        <xsl:text>    /* </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:text> */</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have an input such as:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Foo" type="Bar"/>
    <xsd:simpleType name="Bar">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="32"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>This is a comment</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:schema>
```

It will produce the result below:

```
<?php interface FromXsd {
    abstract public function buildFooXmlString(Bar $a);
    /* This is a comment */
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I got locked into the idea I needed to recur into the `*Type` elements from the `element` nodes. Thanks for breaking me out.

Comment: @VigneshKumar That is a link to this question, which doesn't appear to be your question. What is it that you need help with?